# Implementing "each room is its own voice channel" in Unity 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I am looking to make my first original 2D game. Part of the concept is that every "room" functions like a different "voice channel", much like the ones in discord, but transition is marked by a player physically moving to a different room. So if the map is a building in the form of "stacked boxes", and Red and Yellow are in ROOM A, they are able to hear each other, but not Pink or Orange that are above them in ROOM C or those in ROOM B. However, if Red goes over to ROOM B, they can now speak with Green and Blue but can no longer hear Yellow.

[image]

I have no idea how to go about implementing this. I am using Unity, but I m not experienced at it. I am definitely not sure how to integrate voice chatting into a game, much less so in this manner. If it is possible only under conditions, please do mention them. Any pointers at all would be extremely useful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Inspector of the audio clip you need to set the audio as 3d, set the spatial blend parameter to 1, use the logarithmic rolloff to make the sound change according to distance.